# Migrating ASP.NET 2 site from Oracle 10g to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle10g, asp.net-2.0, oracle12c

I have to migrate a website in ASP.NET 2 currently using Oracle 10g to a new server with Oracle 12c.

When I move the site and try to access from new server,  I am getting Oracle error like "Cannot load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version = 10.1.0.400, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies."

This site was built by another person and I don't have the source to recompile it.  Is there any way to get the site working with Oracle 12c?  I don't have any idea about Oracle and thus I am stuck here.  Any inputs regarding this will very much helpful.

Thanks & Regards

Sujith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem. I managed to get the source from the original programmer and recompiled it by adding reference to Oracle 12c DataAccess component.